# How to keep a few elements in the same position at different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have this menu header bar and @1280x720 it looks like this:

[image]

On wide screens the `about/close` text which is also a side menu button, will be shift to the left

[image]

I've tried to modify the `css` properties adding `position: fixed`, `relative`, `absolute`, etc, on both elements `responsive-menu-pro-header` and `responsive-menu-pro-header-bar-button`but with no good results.

I also have to admit that the menu header bar elements could be made not in the best form; I've used the little coding knowledge that I have in order to build this, may be these elements are shifting in relation to the menu button `about`/`close` (?) at different resolutions.

**The question:** 
Is there any possibility to keep all the elements together at different resolutions (higher than 1280x720) mentaining the initial positions of the button `about`/`close` and the rest of the header menu elements (text/contact links), like we have in the first picture?

I am interested to find a solution only for Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81 64-bit, not crossbrowser or mobile smaller devices.
Website testpage [here](http://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push).

```css
button#responsive-menu-pro-button,#responsive-menu-pro-container {
                display: none;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
            }

            #responsive-menu-pro-container {
                z-index: 99998
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 80000px){
            button#responsive-menu-pro-button {
                    width: 70px;
                    height: 80px;
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 3px;
                    left: px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    transition: transform 2.5s, background-color 0.5s
                }
}

            #responsive-menu-pro-header {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0 5%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                display: none;
                z-index: 99998
            }

            #responsive-menu-pro-header .responsive-menu-pro-header-box {
                display: inline-block
            }

            #responsive-menu-pro-header .responsive-menu-pro-header-box,#responsive-menu-pro-header .responsive-menu-pro-header-box img {
                vertical-align: middle;
                max-width: 100%
            }

            #responsive-menu-pro-header #responsive-menu-pro-header-bar-logo img {
            }

            #responsive-menu-pro-header button#responsive-menu-pro-button {
                position: relative;
                margin: 0;
                left: auto;
                right: auto;
                bottom: auto
            }

            #responsive-menu-pro-header .responsive-menu-pro-header-box {
                margin-right: 2%
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 80000px) {
                #responsive-menu-pro-header {
                    position: fixed;
                    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                    height: 80px;
                    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 14px
                }

                #responsive-menu-pro-header .responsive-menu-pro-header-bar-item {
                    line-height: 80px
                }

                #responsive-menu-pro-header a {
                    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                    text-decoration: none
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar-text1">
 <p style="margin-left: 124px;">⸺ GRAPHIC<br></p>
 <p style="margin-left: 82px;">&amp; EDITORIAL DESIGN.</p>
</div>
<div class="menu-bar-text2">
 <p>TEXT<br></p>
 <p style="margin-left: 35px;">⸺</p>
    <p style="margin-left: 55px;margin-top: -14px;">
  <a href="http://example.com" data-title="HOME"> HOME</a>
 </p>
</div>
<div class="menu-bar-contact">
 <a href="mailto:hello@example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
  <span>SAY HELLO</span>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="responsive-menu-pro-header-bar-button" class="responsive-menu-pro-header-box">
<button id="responsive-menu-pro-button" class="responsive-menu-pro-button responsive-menu-pro-off is-active" type="button" aria-label="Menu" style="transform: translateX(800px);">
 <span class="responsive-menu-pro-box">
        <span class="responsive-menu-pro-inner"></span>
    </span>
 <span class="responsive-menu-pro-label responsive-menu-pro-label-bottom">
  <span class="responsive-menu-pro-button-text" style="display: none;">ABOUT</span>
  <span class="responsive-menu-pro-button-text-open" style="display: inline;">CLOSE</span>
    </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use @media queries for different resolutions.

Comment: I suppose that there are already some media queries set; but honestly I have no clue how to tweak them. If you have the pleasure to elaborate a detailed answer, it will be much appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: Ref: *"Sorry for not posting code sequences"*: You seem to misunderstand the purpose of SO. We're not here to help you with your specific case. We're here to help on well asked questions, general enough to be of use to others with the same type of problem. That's why you need to post your [mcve] in the question itself. So it stays unmodified and the question helps others long after your website changed 3 times over.

Comment: I agree but, how about If I am noob and I don't have the knowledge to recreate the environment 1:1 with the existing site?

Comment: In that case you are, technically, a client. You're not a programmer. And, as stated in the first sentence of the [tour], this website is for programmers.

Comment: Not really, I guess that I could be somewhere between an enthusiast programmer and someone that don't make money from coding. Thanks,

Comment: If you're enthusiast programmer, you should at least try to reproduce the problem here. The more effort you put into it, the more help you'll get. [SO] cannot become a place where clients come and say "Do this for me because I need it". I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179692/discussion-between-typo-and-andrei-gheorghiu).

Comment: @typo_ Please see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ for understanding more about Media queries and how they work. You should try at least and then you can ask here if you face any problem.

Comment: @ParthS007 as far as I can see there is the same value for both elements (the menu button and the menu header bar, text and links) but the behaving is different, am I missing something?  `@media screen and (max-width: 80000px)`

Comment: @Outsource WordPress if you wanna have some fun... I know that these are funny questions for you :) Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve figured out, I’ve changed here:

```
#responsive-menu-pro-header {
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

Replaced with:

```
#responsive-menu-pro-header {
    padding: 0 63px !important;
}
```

Now the menu header bar and the trigger button remain in place aligned at no matter what resolution. Thanks for supporting.